# How to connect to Discogs Api using Zend_Oauth?

Tags: php, zend-framework, discogs-api

I'm attempting to connect to discogs.com api with Zend_Oauth as part of a custom Magento module.

Discogs API details are here:

[accessing](http://www.discogs.com/developers/accessing.html)

[oauth](http://www.discogs.com/developers/oauth.html)

I've followed details for using Zend Oauth here:
[introduction](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html)

Suggested code is as follows...

(I've set up a test account on Discogs so the Key and Secret here are correct and live and can be tested.)

```
$config = array(
    'callbackUrl' => 'http://www.example-discogs-app.co.uk',
    'siteUrl' => 'http://api.discogs.com/oauth',
    'consumerKey' => 'qvJGTkWsbVMGZGYCHCrQ',
    'consumerSecret' => 'iBMnIrhFzoHjqaiVbkhhrmipzcaBwBCc'
    );
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);

// fetch a request token
$token = $consumer->getRequestToken();

// persist the token to storage
$_SESSION['DISCOGS_REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($token);

// redirect the user
$consumer->redirect();
```

I get a request token and get redirected to: api.discogs.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xyzrequesttoken

With this displayed:

> "{"message": "The requested resource was not found."}"

NB: When I run the same code against Twitter API Oauth with the relevant account key details it works and redirects to twitter for access confirmation as it should.

I've tried various $config settings with no luck, e.g. requestScheme, requestMethod,.

I figured it could be something to do with required headers so I've also tried replacing $consumer->redirect(); with the following...
($token being extracted from the $token response above)

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setHeaders('Content-Type: application/json');
$client->setHeaders('User-Agent: +Xyz');
$client->setUri('http://api.discogs.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token='.$token);
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$response = $client->request();
```

I get the same response:

> "{"message": "The requested resource was not found."}"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The kind people at discogs pointed out that the authorize url should be www not api so the correct config that works looks like this:

```
    $config = array(
        'callbackUrl' => http://www.example-discogs-app.co.uk,
        'consumerKey' => 'tJOGhRhfsCQKnGCaOZin',
        'consumerSecret' => 'dxyrhywgvMgVqrZsmncCrQyAXnRHwZVq',
        'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token',
        'authorizeUrl' => 'http://www.discogs.com/oauth/authorize',
        'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://api.discogs.com/oauth/access_token',
    );
```